# Scene cleanup before export

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm trying to make a script to do a bunch of cleanup operations on the scene before exporting it to fbx.

How can I select all Mesh/Poly models in the scene to delete them ?
I tried using the isKindOf GeometryClass but bones are selected as well ...

I'm also trying to change all object display property to "By layer", but I can't get it to show up in the Maxscript listener.

Here is exactly what I need to do :

1. Hide by category > none
2. Unhide all
3. Unfreeze all
4. Set display property to "By layer"
5. Delete all 3d Mesh/Poly object from the scene
6. Export to fbx

Finally, is there a way to run this script on multiple Max file through the command line ?

Thanks

---

This is what I ended up using (ExportAnimationFbx.ms) :

```
filename=maxops.mxsCmdLineArgs[#filename]
loadmaxfile filename

hideByCategory.none()
unhide objects
unfreeze objects
objects.displayByLayer = on
delete (for obj in objects where isKindOf obj.baseObject Editable_Mesh or isKindOf obj.baseObject Editable_Poly or isKindOf obj Plane collect obj)

exportFileName = maxops.mxsCmdLineArgs[#exportfilename]

--Geometry------------------------------------------------------------------------
FBXExporterSetParam "SmoothingGroups" false
FBXExporterSetParam "NormalsPerPoly" false
FBXExporterSetParam "TangentSpaceExport" false
FBXExporterSetParam "SmoothMeshExport" false
FBXExporterSetParam "Preserveinstances" false
FBXExporterSetParam "SelectionSetExport" false
FBXExporterSetParam "GeomAsBone" true
FBXExporterSetParam "ColladaTriangulate" false
FBXExporterSetParam "PreserveEdgeOrientation" false
--Animation------------------------------------------------------------------------
FBXExporterSetParam "Animation" true
FBXExporterSetParam "ExportAnimationOnly" false
FBXExporterSetParam "BakeAnimation" true
FBXExporterSetParam "Skin" true
--Cameras------------------------------------------------------------------------
FBXExporterSetParam "Cameras" false
--Lights------------------------------------------------------------------------
FBXExporterSetParam "Lights" false
--Embed Media--------------------------------------------------------------------
FBXExporterSetParam "EmbedTextures" false
--Units----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Axis Conversion-----------------------------------------------------------------
FBXExporterSetParam "AxisConversionMethod" "Fbx_Root" --"None", "Animation", or "Fbx_Root".
FBXExporterSetParam "UpAxis" "Z" 
--UI----------------------------------------------------------------
FBXExporterSetParam "ShowWarnings" true
FBXExporterSetParam "GenerateLog" false
--FBX File Format----------------------------------------------------------------
FBXExporterSetParam "ASCII" false
FBXExporterSetParam "FileVersion" "FBX201400"

exportFile (exportFileName) #noprompt selectedOnly:false using:FBXEXP
```

And this is the command I loop through in my batch file :

```
"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\3ds Max 2019\3dsmaxbatch.exe" ExportAnimationFbx.ms -mxsString filename:"myfoldername\maxfilename.max" -mxsString exportfilename:"assetname.fbx"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the initial scene setup:

```
hideByCategory.none()
unhide objects
unfreeze objects
objects.displayByLayer = on
delete (for obj in objects where isKindOf obj Editable_Mesh or isKindOf obj Editable_Poly collect obj)
```

As for the FBX export, refer to [this How to control Max's FBX exporter post](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-max-programming/how-to-control-max-s-fbx-exporter/m-p/6856129/highlight/true#M15515). If you're using max 2018.4 or newer, [this series of blog posts](https://area.autodesk.com/blogs/max-station/updated-3ds-max-batch-1/) will walk you through 3ds max commandline access.

Comment: Everything works except the last part to delete the models. The problem is those are not collapsed as mesh/poly, they are 3d primitives, skinned models, etc ...

Comment: I tried using "canConvertTo obj Editable_Poly", the problem is this will delete all the bones/biped

Comment: It's about what criteria you set, if you want anything that has a mesh/poly baseobject, use `isKindOf obj.baseObject Editable_Mesh` instead of testing the `obj` itself.

Comment: Thanks @Swordslayer that works for the mesh/poly objects. Is there any way to select all 3d mesh/poly primitives types as well without listing them one by one ? like Plane, box, etc ... everything with triangles/polygons (but not bones/biped). Cheers

Comment: Standard+Extended primitives would fall under `matchPattern obj.baseObject.category pattern:"*primitive*"`

Comment: Thanks for your help! The maxscript and batch files are working great :)